# QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat differents QGIS 2 QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3

A long time ago I wrote a plugin for my own use. The plugin works fine in QGIS 2.18 but not in QGIS 3.1. I used the script `2to3` and solved most problems.The only problem I am left with is the following.

First my code that I use.

```
import os.path

CSVDIR = 'd:/QGIS/Temp_map/TestCSV/2018/'
DESTDIR = 'd:/QGIS/Temp_map/TestSHP/2018/'

if not os.path.exists(DESTDIR):
os.makedirs(DESTDIR)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(CSVDIR):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file).replace('/', '/')
            filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fullname))[0]
            uri = 'file:///%s?crs=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&decimal=%s&useHeader=no&' % (fullname, 'EPSG:4326', ';', 'Field_7', 'Field_6', ',')
            layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'my_layer', 'delimitedtext')
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, DESTDIR + filename + '.shp', 'CP1250', None, 'ESRI Shapefile')

    self.iface.messageBar().clearWidgets()
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

    QMessageBox.information(iface.mainWindow(), "CSV naar Shape",
        "Uw Shapefiles zijn aangemaakt!", QMessageBox.Ok )
```

This code works in QGIS 2.18 but give the following error in QGIS 3.0.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
  exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
  TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 4 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  overload 2: argument 4 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  overload 3: argument 3 has unexpected type 'str'
```

What can I do to make this working?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`writeAsVectorFormat()` function expects `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem`for argument 4.

Replacing `None` with `layer.crs()` will solve your problem.

For more information, refer to [QgsVectorFileWriter Class Reference](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#ae54dce04a5fc1a570b6c4c4f7dfa064d)