# "QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments did not match any overloaded call" in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

The following code iterates through a folder of .xyz files and is supposed to copy them into another folder.

```
for file in glob.glob("*.xyz"):
    uri = "file:///" + inputDir +"/"+ file + "?type=csv&delimiter=%s&crs=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (" ", crs, "field_1", "field_2")
    name = file.replace('.xyz', '')
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, "delimitedtext")
    outputPath = outDir + file
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, outputPath, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), "CSV", layerOptions='GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ')
```

However, I get the following error message:

> TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:   overload 1: argument 'layerOptions' has unexpected type 'str'   overload 2: argument 4 has unexpected type 'QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem'   overload 3: argument 3 has unexpected type 'str'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/denni/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Clip_XYZ\Clip_XYZ.py",
>   line 283, in run
>       self.moveFiles()   File "C:/Users/denni/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Clip_XYZ\Clip_XYZ.py",
>   line 251, in moveFiles
>       QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, outputPath, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), "CSV", layerOptions='GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ') TypeError:
>   QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments did not match any
>   overloaded call:   overload 1: argument 'layerOptions' has unexpected
>   type 'str'   overload 2: argument 4 has unexpected type
>   'QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem'   overload 3: argument 3 has unexpected
>   type 'str'

I don't understand the error. When I check the [documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat), layerOptions is a str, argument 4 is the crs, and argument 3 is also a str.

Are the docs wrong? Or is there something else wrong with my code?

Comment: I am having the same problem, even when I don't include any layerOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer is posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279655/95891)**

The third parameter should be `layer.crs()`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the answer. layerOptions expects a list of strings. Thus, `layerOptions=['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ']`is correct.

I still don't get the error for overload 2 and 3 though. But now these errors don't appear anymore.

Comment: Where to put this command? I still have the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 3.0+ version of QGIS then you will have to change *writeAsVectorFormat* to *writeAsVectorFormatV2*, which means you are going to need new parameters(transformContext(), SaveVectorOptions()).
So it should be something like that:

```
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = 'utf-8'
options.fieldNameSource = QgsVectorFileWriter.Original

error, error_string = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(lyr, 
outputPath, QgsProject.instance().transformContext(), options)
```